# Regex to detect a word with more than 1 capital letters

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex which matches a word with more than 1 capital letters.
The location of the capital letters can be anywhere.

It should match:

```
ABc
aBC
ABC
```

It should not match:

```
Abc
aBc
abC
abc
```

Comment: Which regex engine? Do you consider `É` to be a letter? Does your entire input only consist of a single word, or do you want to find words in a larger sentence? Should `AbC` match? Your problem isn't well-defined yet...

Comment: Only normal English letters.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you want only alphanumeric ("word") characters:

```
\w*[A-Z]\w*[A-Z]\w*
```

The \w's are all spots for any alphanumeric character (or underscore, to be precise), and the [A-Z] matches any uppercase letter, assuming you're using normal ascii letters. This regex will match string with *at least* 2 uppercase letters, but any number of them.

If the words can be anything, not just containing "word" characters, you can use

```
.*[A-Z].*[A-Z].*
```

And if you want to restrict it to exactly the set of "normal english letters:"

```
[a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*
```

Comment: `[A-Z].*[A-Z]` is sufficient. There're no needss to test anything before and after.

Comment: @M42 what about "aBBa"? That will match the "BB", sure, but I think he wants to match the whole word.